# PAM Authentication and SSH access based on user info stored in sqlite3

Tags: linux, ssh, pam, sqlite

I have an application that runs on a `Linux` box. The application stores all its user information (like - `username`, `password`, `ssh-allowed`, etc) in an `sqlite3` database as follows.

```
username        password        ssh-allowed
admin           X               y   
regularuser     X               n
```

The application users will login to a GUI to use the application. But all the application users who have their `ssh-allowed` as `y` are allowed to login to the `Linux` box using `ssh`. Other application users (with `ssh-allowed` as `n`) are not allowed to login to the `Linux` box using `ssh`.

So in the above case `admin` user will be allowed to `ssh` to the `Linux` box but `regularuser` will be denied `ssh` access to the `Linux` box.

W.r.t the GUI, in order to perform `authentication` using `PAM` for user info stored in `sqlite`, I use [libpam-sqlite](https://github.com/Sectoid/libpam-sqlite). Actually, I have modified it to work with `sqlite3` database and it is available [here](https://github.com/sangeeths/libpam-sqlite).

Now to the question: When an application user attempts to login to the `Linux` box, How can I perform `authentication` and then decide to either allow or deny `ssh` access based on the `ssh-allowed` parameter that is stored in the `sqlite3` database using `PAM` (or any other way)?

Please NOTE: All the user info is store in the `sqlite3` database only and NOT in `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/group` files. IOW the application does not have rights to add/remove records in the `/etc` files.

NOTE2: I had the same question posted in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718631/pam-authentication-and-ssh-access-based-on-user-info-stored-in-sqlite3); thought this is a better forum for Linux related questions.

Comment: You usually don't want to cross post the same Q on multiple SE sites, it's a reason for us to close it here, usually a reason on the other SE sites. You might want to pick one site and close it on the other. This site is likely the better place for it. Please go ahead and close the SO one.

Answer (score 1):

#### pam_exec

I think you can do what you want using the [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules) module [`pam_exec`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_exec.html). PAM items are passed to a script that is defined to run as environment variables. Here's an example notification script that shows the variables being passed in:

#### Setup

```
#!/bin/sh
[ "$PAM_TYPE" = "open_session" ] || exit 0
# echo "User: $PAM_USER"
# echo "Ruser: $PAM_RUSER"
# echo "Rhost: $PAM_RHOST"
# echo "Service: $PAM_SERVICE"
# echo "TTY: $PAM_TTY"

result=$(sqlite3 /path/to/file.db \
    "select ssh-allow from sometable where user = \"$PAM_USER\"")

if [ "$results" == "y" ]; then
  ...login...
else
  ...no login...
fi
```

You then create a corresponding PAM rule like this:

```
session    optional     pam_exec.so /usr/local/bin/checkssh-login
```

A script using this approach could be crafted that could perform a look up in your `sqlite` database file using the user's name that was passed in as `$PAM_USER`. If that user is allowed to SSH in, then the script could simply drop through, otherwise it could block the user from continuing on with their login attempt.

#### References

- [Login notifications, pam_exec scripting](http://blog.stalkr.net/2010/11/login-notifications-pamexec-scripting.html)